# Obtaining Immediate larger number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on a program question for python. This is the question:

> **Immediate Previous Larger Number**
>
> N numbers are passed as input to the program. The program must print
>   the immediate previous larger number. If there is no such larger
>   number print 0 for that specific number.
>
> Note: As N can be as high as 100000, optimize your algorithm to avoid
>   timeout.
>
> Input Format: The first line contains N. The second line contains N
>   numbers separated by a space.
>
> Output Format: The first line contains N numbers which denote the
>   immediate previous larger number.
>
> Boundary Conditions: 2 <= N <= 100000
>
> Example Input/Output 1: Input: 11 455 346 76 304 488 374 385 433 350 9
>   1000
>
> Output: 0 455 346 346 0 488 488 488 433 350 0

I worked out and came upto a certain point where my code gives the largest number before a certain number but not the immediate largest number previous to it.

```
a = []
n = int(input())
number = input().split()
b = [number for number in number]
assert len(b)==n and n>=0
for i in range(0,len(b)):
    a.append(b[0:i])
for j in range(0,len(b)):
    if j==0:
        print(0)
    else:
        m = int(max(a[j]))
        if int(b[j])>m:
            print(0)
        else:
            print(m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work  (I am taking the input as a list, you can modify your code accordingly). There is also no need to tell the script the number of elements as it can be handled in a for loop.

```
f = [455, 346, 76, 304, 488, 374, 385, 433, 350, 9, 1000]

def xyzzy(foo):
    output = [0]
    for i in range(1, len(foo)):
        _tmp = [0] + [y for y in foo[0:i] if y > foo[i]]
        output.append(_tmp[-1])

    return output

print(xyzzy(f))
```

If you want to have the length of the array as the first number in the list, then just ignore it in the for loop of `xyzzy` and start the range from two. It is not needed for anything in this but if it is present in your input data, you can easily ignore it.

**EDIT**

This answer is based on the assumption that 11 is not part of your input array. Your output does not seem to make sense to me if it is part of it as you have then 12 input elements and 11 output elements, but you describe N numbers for both input and output format. If you expect different number of output values as compared to input values, please edit your question.

Comment: why `output = [0]`? why not `output = []`?

Comment: How I understand the question (I admit it is a bit vague), the first number in the output array always defaults to zero as there are no larger numbers before the first number of the input array.  Of course we could set output as [] and set the range as (0, len(foo)), it would work as well and do the same thing. I just chose to do it like this.

Comment: in this case, the 2nd number is also `0` in the output which is not desired right?

Comment: Again, as I understand the question, 11 in the input array is the length of the rest of the array (input length is 12, output is 11).  It does not seem to be processed for the output array. The first zero comes from 455 (no smaller numbers than it as it is the first number and nothing precedes it, hence zero).  See my comment about length of the array in the input after the code and means of ignoring it if it has to be there.   I understood this question being about an algorithm to solve the output number selection problem.

Comment: Comment about input format says "first line contains N", the second line contains N numbers.  In the example there is only one input line but the first element of the input array appears to be the array length, which is not needed in my algorithm.  The question is extremely vague in this sense. If you understood it differently, feel free to post another answer. My algorithm is based on my interpretation of the question - and focusing on the part OP seems to struggle with - the output number selection.

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer to explain how I understood the question and the input values. It may not be the right interpretation of clearly conflicting explanation and example (one line in example, two lines in text + expectation of N input values and N output values but example containing 12 inputs and 11 outputs) but my interpretation of a missing line feed between 11 and 455 makes sense to me.